# VHDL: Vivado 2016.4: Implementation failure on multidriven net

Tags: vhdl, synthesis, vivado

Upon synthesis, Vivado 2016.4 complains about "multidriven nets". However, in trying to find the error I only managed to further prove that there is no problem with the design, so perhaps my understanding of the problem is incorrect.

The situation is as follows:

- Consider two components: `lnx1_buffer`; `lnx1_datacentre`.
- Both components have an `inout` port called `databus`, by which they are interconnected in a toplevel component.
- Both components also take two control signals as inputs:

  - `en_db_drive_from_pt`
  - `en_alu_int_db_drive`

---

`lnx1_buffer` drives its `databus` port as follows:

```
buffer_inout.databus <=
    q when not (en_db_drive_from_pt or en_alu_int_db_drive) = '1' else
    (others => 'Z');
```

`lnx1_datacentre` drives its `databus` as follows:

```
datacentre_inout.databus <=
    db_int when (en_db_drive_from_pt or en_alu_int_db_drive) = '1' else
    (others => 'Z');
```

Evidently from the logic, there is never a situation when both components are driving the bus; the `not` inversion of the control signal logic takes care of that. And further, as one sees below, the synthesizer generates appropriate `TRISTATE` buffers.

Nonetheless, the design does not synthesize cleanly:

```
[Synth 8-3352] multi-driven net buffer_inout[databus][8] with 1st driver pin 'cpu0/datacentre0/i_61/O' ["/home/maxim/development/vhdl/xprojects/project_intro/project_intro.srcs/sources_1/new/lnx1_datacentre.vhd":9]
[Synth 8-3352] multi-driven net buffer_inout[databus][8] with 2nd driver pin 'cpu0/buf0/i_26/O' ["/home/maxim/development/vhdl/xprojects/project_intro/project_intro.srcs/sources_1/new/lnx1_buffer.vhd":8]
[Synth 8-3352] multi-driven net buffer_inout[databus][0] with 1st driver pin 'cpu0/datacentre0/i_53/O' ["/home/maxim/development/vhdl/xprojects/project_intro/project_intro.srcs/sources_1/new/lnx1_datacentre.vhd":9]
[Synth 8-3352] multi-driven net buffer_inout[databus][0] with 2nd driver pin 'cpu0/buf0/i_18/O' ["/home/maxim/development/vhdl/xprojects/project_intro/project_intro.srcs/sources_1/new/lnx1_buffer.vhd":8]
[Synth 8-3352] multi-driven net buffer_inout[databus][9] with 1st driver pin 'cpu0/datacentre0/i_62/O' ["/home/maxim/development/vhdl/xprojects/project_intro/project_intro.srcs/sources_1/new/lnx1_datacentre.vhd":9]
```

...and implementation fails altogether with the following message

```
[DRC 23-20] Rule violation (MDRV-1) Multiple Driver Nets - Net cpu0/datacentre0/datacentre_inout[databus][0] has multiple drivers: cpu0/buf0/buffer_inout[databus][0]_INST_0/O, cpu0/datacentre0/datacentre_inout[databus][0]_INST_0/O.
[DRC 23-20] Rule violation (MDRV-1) Multiple Driver Nets - Net cpu0/datacentre0/datacentre_inout[databus][10] has multiple drivers: cpu0/buf0/buffer_inout[databus][10]_INST_0/O, cpu0/datacentre0/datacentre_inout[databus][10]_INST_0/O.
[DRC 23-20] Rule violation (MDRV-1) Multiple Driver Nets - Net cpu0/datacentre0/datacentre_inout[databus][11] has multiple drivers: cpu0/buf0/buffer_inout[databus][11]_INST_0/O, cpu0/datacentre0/datacentre_inout[databus][11]_INST_0/O.
[DRC 23-20] Rule violation (MDRV-1) Multiple Driver Nets - Net cpu0/datacentre0/datacentre_inout[databus][12] has multiple drivers: cpu0/buf0/buffer_inout[databus][12]_INST_0/O, cpu0/datacentre0/datacentre_inout[databus][12]_INST_0/O.
[DRC 23-20] Rule violation (MDRV-1) Multiple Driver Nets - Net cpu0/datacentre0/datacentre_inout[databus][13] has multiple drivers: cpu0/buf0/buffer_inout[databus][13]_INST_0/O, cpu0/datacentre0/datacentre_inout[databus][13]_INST_0/O.
...
```

... for each bit of the `databus` bus.

I can absolutely guarantee that there is no other logic that could be possibly intervening. The snippets of code I've posted so far are indeed the only signals associated with driving the port, and Ive checked the control signals  and proven to myself that they are indeed coming from the same source, and that they are not unconnected.

**The only other cause I can speculate to** is that due to the switching time of the gates, there is a brief moment when both buffers are enabled, and are thus momentarily driven by both components. If this is the case, how can I introduce a delay to prevent this from happening?

---

Below are images of the RTL schematic implementation, if they are of use. The control signals and `databus` bus are highlighted in blue. Everything else should be irrelevant, as it is not immediately involved in the driving logic.

buffer: Notice the OR'd signals go to a multiplexer that implements the inversion
[image]

datacentre (the two topmost leftmost signals are the control signals):
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you write `q when not <expr> = '1'` instead of `q when <expr> /= '1'`? Are you sure of what your code does?

Comment: As far as I understand, `databus` is an internal pin rather than a port. Most of the FPGA families don't support high-impedance on internal logic. Could it be the case for your FPGA also?

Comment: @ahmedus If that is the case, how else would I implement a bus that is used by multiple components?

Comment: @MaxB Maybe you can use two pins, then each pin transmits data in one direction. If there is a third component that receives `databus` signal, a multiplexer should work for it.

Comment: You are using std_logic types right? Instead of std_ulogic?

Comment: @digitaLink Yes

Comment: @MaxB "how else would I implement a bus that is used by multiple components?" By building a bus arbiter. You should read up in busses used on FPGAs. E.g. wishbone, AXI, Avalon, etc.

Comment: Internal tristates haven't been supported since the XC4000 series, which predated the Virtex-1. It's been a while...